# Annoying red borders surrounding elements in the Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

After some use of the inspect feature in the Chrome browser the other day, I have annoying borders appearing around browser elements in normal usage. Might this be a setting that I unintentionally enabled in Chrome developer features?

[image: example-1]
[image: example-2]
[image: example-3]

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, the solution was to turn off hardware acceleration in Chrome. I'm still not sure why this was the cause. The element border issue also appeared alongside some images failing to render when browsing.